# Which dependencies are needed for hibernate3-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, dependencies, hibernate-tools

I use the plugin version 3.0

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</plugin>
```

I don't know which dependencies are needed, which version of hibernate-tools I must add? Do I need to add hibernate-core too?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The [website](http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/examples/simple-example.html) says that the simplest plugin definition is this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>@pom.version@</version>
<configuration>
    <hibernatetool>
        <jpaconfiguration/>
    </hibernatetool>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Where `@pom.version@` should be the latest plugin version. You won't need any other dependencies, that's what maven is for. Each plugin loads its own dependencies via the maven dependency mechanism.

Comment: But if I do not add `hibernate-tools` I have this error:` There was an error creating the AntRun task. An Ant BuildException has occured: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`

Comment: Can you achieve your goals without AntRun? It would be better if you could -- AntRun steps outside the maven model and often results in an non-portable, non-repeatable build.

Comment: And, shouldn't that be part of the question?

Comment: And, finally, you're reporting a problem with antrun, not with your plugin dependency.

Comment: I followed the [example](http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/examples/run-multiple-goals.html)  in the website. I want to do reverse engineering using hibernate-tools.